# Too many or too long tags mess up the alignment

Tags: bug, tags

**Red circle #1:** Normal.

**Red circle #2:** Not normal (atleast AFAIK).

[image]

Is this a bug / feature or status-bydesign?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) since:

[image]

The metadata automatically gets a newline whenever there is not enough space available on the initial line. When the current tags are being pushed down, this simply enlarges the initial `div.tags`.

However, this case happens because `google-newsstand-producer` is so long that it automatically jumps to a new line. A better 'solution' for this would be to re-order the current tags. But then again, is it really needed?

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks alot :) I don't think that a change is needed, I was mostly just curious as to why this was happening.